# With Commerce Product taxonomy term view, is there a way to have page title set to the translated term title?

Tags: 8, views, commerce, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

The only way to have the taxonomy term name in the title of a taxonomy term Commerce Products view page I've found so far is the example view in the [estore theme](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/estore/-/blob/8.x-1.14/config/optional/views.view.products.yml) (I still don't get how tid which should stand for Term ID becomes the title field value):

[image: screenshot of the View > Advanced settings]

[image: screenshot of contextual filter: Taxonomy term: Term ID]

The problem is that the title shown is not translated on multilingual sites when the term definitely has a proper translation. Is there any way to show that title translated?

For some reason there are no `Product: Has taxonomy term ID` as there is `Content: Has taxonomy term ID` in the default taxonomy term view that is displaying the title translated.

AFAIU `{{ arguments.tid|t }}` is not the way because it will go through a different subsystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to workaround it in code by modifying [an example posted by djg_tram](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2915934#comment-13903137):

```php
/**
 * @file
 * Workaround for taxonomy term title not being i18zed.
 */
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_render().
 */
function exposed_filter_workaround_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
  $view_id = 'products';
  $view_display = 'page_category';

  if ($view->id() == $view_id && $view->current_display == $view_display) {
    $lang_id = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();

    $term_id = $view->args[0];
    $term = Term::load($term_id);

    $term_translated = $term->getTranslation($lang_id);
    $view->setTitle($term_translated->label());
  }
}
```